# Symfony: set cookie from model?

Tags: cookies, symfony1, model

Is it possible to set (or retrieve) cookies from the model layer?

Granted that the model layer is intended for 'business logic', the logic I need requires a little interaction with the request and response.

Comment: This seems like an architectural problem, can you tell more why you need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you process and store your cookie value in your model:

```
class ModelTable
{
  protected $cookie = null;

  public function getCookie()
  {
    return $this->cookie;
  }

  public function setCookie($value)
  {
    $this->cookie = $value;
  }
}
```

And use postExecute of your action to set cookie:

```
class yourActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    ModelTable::getInstance()->setCookie('bla');
  }

  public function postExecute()
  {
    $cookie = ModelTable::getInstance()->getCookie();
    $this->getResponse()->setCookie('name', $cookie, time() + 24 * 3600);
  }
}
```

It's always better to stick to MVC model: controller calls model for info and build the response, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()` to get the instance for the `sfWebResponse`. On that instance you can call the `setCookie()` method. (or chain it directly).

But be warned: you'll never know for sure if the cookie has been set (depending on the action in the controller), so maybe there is a better design?

Comment: Adding calls to sfContext in the Model will also make it impossible to Unit test your methods. This singleton must not be call in model.

Comment: Yes, maybe I didn't warn enough.. This isn't a recommended way, but it works. As I said, changing the design (like Dziamid) is a lot better.